# Create new folder from public and use as a admin side in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel so if my question is not up to the mark then forgive me but I googled it and not found answer as per my requirement.I follow https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/setup-different-frontend-backend-endpoints-in-laravel-51 && https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/splitting-admin-and-front-end

**MY NEED :**

I want 2 entry point for my laravel application. one is for front user and second for admin user.

I am using laravel latest version (5.3.26).

As we know public folder is the entry point for laravel application.

**Ex : http://localhost/news_report_old/public/index.php**

Using above URl we can enter into application. Right ?

Now I want to create new entry point for Admin So I thing I can copy public folder and rename it so my work is done but I missing something and I can't figure out what I am missing ?

**EX : http://localhost/news_report_old/admin/index.php**

So when I open above URL I want to open Admin side.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your setup in your development environment? Are you using xampp? homestead?

Comment: @aceraven777 i AM USING LAMP on linux

Comment: @watson LAMP = Linux Apache... no need to clarify that you are on Linux. What you are doing is bad design, reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

You, don't need to copy **public** folder. That is terrific idea. (Don't ever mess with core/structure framework code, unless you have no any other option)

You can distinguish front end and admin panel easily using router and middleware.

You should create a custom middelware:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

And routing can be like:

routes/web.php:

```
// List of all front end routes:

Route::get('/', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); 
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about'); 

// List of all admin routes

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController')
});
```